# Scroll View doesn't show full content

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I have an XML file that has a ScrollView with one child LinearLayout. in tried to inflate a layout which has a TableLayout and some other child views. but for some reason that last button in the tableTable layout is not fully visible.

**Update:-**  For trial i moved the button up..but the same happened to the last textView..so i can get from that the problem is either with ScrollView-LinearLayout or TableLayout.

**MYScrollView.xml**

```
          <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:padding="15dp"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lo1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border"   
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**MyTableLayout.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LiLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left">

<com.example.tamarud.FontTextView
    android:id="@+id/textv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="La campagne Rebelle"
    android:textColor="#611711" />

<com.example.tamarud.Header2
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="(Pour la destitution de Mohamed Mursi Al Ayat)" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <com.example.tamarud.Bodytext
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="• Parce que la sécurité n'a pas été retrouvée à Ce jour … On vous refuse" />

    <com.example.tamarud.Bodytext
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="• Parce que le démunis est toujours ignoré … On vous refuse" />

    <com.example.tamarud.Bodytext
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="• Parce que nous sommes encore en train de mendier des prêts de l'extérieur … On vous refuse" />
      <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"             
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">

    <com.example.tamarud.Bodytext
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#611711"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Quartier"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner01"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"             
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip">

    <com.example.tamarud.Bodytext
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#611711"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="E-mail"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText07"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Entrez E-mail"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
  </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#611711"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="I Accept"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

   </TableLayout>
```

[image: here is a picture]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution is to wrap the **ScrollView** in a **RelativeLayout** and give them both **Width** and **Height** of **fill_parent**

Answer (score 3):

This is a way old question but ill still answer it cause I was looking for an answer myself and found a solution. You need to remove your Margins and replace them with paddings.

Your original code:

```
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

What it should be:

```
android:paddingTop="10dp"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try explicitly setting a dp height on the last button.

```
android:layout_height="48dp"
```

or whatever height u feel it should be. I believe Google recommends 48dp for clickable things like buttons.

You could also try setting it up like the following, removing the bottom button from the table layout and setting the table layout to be aligned above the button:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/scrollContainer"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/myTable"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomButton"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/bottomButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but none of them worked what worked as to wrap the whole scrollView in a RelativeLayout Rather than only the TableLayout..

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your padding and margin top.

Comment: I tried it. nothing happened. just for trial i moved the button up..but the effect happend to the last textView..so i can get from that the problem is eother with ScrollView-LinearLayout-TableLayout

Comment: And you tried removing padding + margins on ScrollView, LinearLayout and TableLayout to see if that's it?

Comment: yeah i tried..still the same.. it only gets fixed if i removed any of the textViews

Answer (score -1):

I'm always facing this silly issue, and what I'm doing is adding `layout_marginBottom` to the main view or the last view equals to the height of the last view or even equals to the clipped area that needs to be shown, like:

```
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   .
   .>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/main"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         .
         .
         <!--some views-->
         .
         .

         <!--last view-->
         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

         </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```